# Purpose of clutch in transmission with multiple neutrals

Tags: transmission, clutch, small-engine

I am currently repurposing the transmission and clutch of a pretty old walking tractor (Bucher K3). Here is a picture of exactly that transmission:

[image: Image of clutch and motor]

So this transmission has 3 forward and one reverse gear. It is laid out in such a way that between each gear there is a neutral, i.e. you go from 1 to neutral to 2 to neutral to 3, back to neutral to 2 to neutral to 1 to neutral to reverse. This is a common pattern I have seen in old walking tractors/mowers. All of the previous ones I have worked on were directly connected to the engine since having neutral between gears essentially acts as a "clutch" thus no other clutch is needed.

However this transmission also has a clutch, you can see it sitting on top of the transmission, its a friction plate that is pressed into/released from the clutch bell on the motor.

My plan was to just shift without using the clutch since this works on other devices with similar transmissions, but then I was thinking there is probably a reason why there would be a clutch in addition. Is this true? Or is it superfluous?

Comment: Curious if the reason for this is basically for it to double clutch. No clue, lol.

Comment: Thinking harder about this (yes I do that once in a while :o), I think your not giving the clutch its due. You still need to disconnect the power from the transmission in order to get it into gear (you should be able slip it out of gear without the clutch). If you don't use a clutch, you're going to be grinding gears or sharply forcing it to get into gear. I think the bigger question about the transmission is *why is there a neutral between each gear?*

Comment: How much experience do you have with manual transmissions in automobiles?

Comment: Perhaps this xmission is a non-synchromesh type made before synchromesh xmission gears allowed many more people to shift without damaging gears. Non-synchromesh xmissions are very old school, most likely where double clutching was required. I think this was around the transition from horse drawn carriages to cars and trucks. Gear mashing occurred frequently until time and experience allowed drivers to shift smoothly. This old gear box needs the clutch to completely disengage the xmission to allow shifting, probably when vehicle travel stopped before shifting into the next gear.

Comment: What is extraordinary about moving through neutral between each gear? The vast majority of motor vehicle manual transmissions are like that. Only motorcycles and a few high-performance cars have a sequential (manual) gearbox.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 good point, I wish I still had one of the old mowers I had without any clutch to open up the gearbox, but they all worked well so I didnt have to. I just remember all of them having really complicated shifting patterns on the stick. Maybe the shifter also somehow operated the clutch and I am looking at this from the wrong direction :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Been driving at least one manual car all the time but I kinda blurred that out when working on small machines...

Comment: @WeatherVane @F Dryer Interestingly the machines without clutch I have are from the 1920s, the one pictured is from the 1950s